# Select filtered records from a table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table on a **SQL Server 2008 R2** database:

```
╔══════════════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╗
║        Team Name         ║ Project Code ║ Actioned ║
╠══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════╣
║ DC & Facilities Services ║ ZZ794419     ║ No       ║
║ DC & Facilities Services ║ ZZ794419     ║ Yes      ║
║ DC & Facilities Services ║ ZZ795164     ║ No       ║
║ DC & Facilities Services ║ ZZ795247     ║ No       ║
╚══════════════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╝
```

`Team Name` and `Project Code` together are the composite primary key. In this case, **the returned results I'm after are the last 3 rows**. When a (project and team) has multiple rows (i.e. the first 2 rows in the table above), I want to select only the row(s) where `Actioned` is `'Yes'`. If the project and team has only `'No'` in **Actioned** (i.e. the last 2 rows in the table above), they also need to be included in my results.

Is there a way to get the results from a `SELECT` statement? It seems difficult to define the `WHERE` clause to get the expected results.

Comment: Can you have a pair of Project Code entries with both having "No" for `Actioned`?

Comment: No, there is no duplicates. i.e.: a unique (project and team) cannot have two entries of "No" in Actioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUM() OVER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        Y = SUM(CASE WHEN Actioned = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY TeamName, ProjectCode),
        N = SUM(CASE WHEN Actioned = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY TeamName, ProjectCode)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
    TeamName, ProjectCode, Actioned
FROM CTE
WHERE
    (Y = 1 AND Actioned = 'Yes')
    OR (Y = 0)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/765ca/1/0)

Comment: thank you very much - that's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: You might want to look at Tim's answer. His is faster imo.

Answer (score 3):

You can try grouping on the combination of the `Team Name` and `Project Code` columns, and then using the `MAX()` function to select the record with `'Yes'` in the event that both `'Yes'` and `'No'` appear for a given group combination.

```
SELECT `Team Name`, `Project Code`, MAX(`Actioned`) AS 'Actioned'
FROM table
GROUP BY `Team Name`, `Project Code`
```